# What does "h2" mean on technical drawing?

Tags: technical-drawing

I have a technical drawing, but I can't understand the "h2". The "h2" points to a hole, and I don't understand it. Can you please give me an answer? Thanks!

Comment: A picture showing reference to h2 would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H2 refers to the tolerance of the hole - whether it’s an upper or lower case letter shows if it’s a hole or shaft tolerance. In this case, as you mention it’s on a hole, I would expect it to be “H6”, which means for an 6.00mm hole, it would be acceptable if manufactured in the range 6.00-6.03mm in diameter.

[image]

Comment: The red annotations on the image are not my own - it’s a screenshot from this video that I found on google images https://youtu.be/c8TKftViusQ